# Is it enough to just make property int for foreign key in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys

I want to make a foreign key one-to-one relation between Mysql table in a hibernate java class .

DB:

**table1 :**

```
Id   int         PK
name varchar(10) NN
```

**table2 :**

```
Id      int         PK
name    varchar(10) NN
tabe1Id int         FK
```

Code :

**JavaClass1**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
public class table1{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}
```

**JavaClass2**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table2")
public class table2{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name="table1Id")
    private int JavaClass1Id;
}
```

Is It Enough to write like this ? to store the JavaClass1Id in JavaClass2 as an integer without make a relation in hibernate to the another class ?

Comment: It is a very, very bad idea to use ID fields in your object model. The object model should use the `equals` relationship of the object model. The `id` fields will do their magic in the data model, without being exposed to the object  model. Don't model tables. Model objects. Use `@OneToMany`, etc. to get what you want, e.g., `@Entity public class Order { ... @OneToMany List<LineItem> lineItems; ...}`. Study the JPA tutorial.

Comment: You usually don't use the type of the key `int`, but instead the other class `table1`. You additionally need the `@OneToOne`-annotation. As far as I know, there are some Hibernate-pitfalls related to one to one - relations.

Answer (score 0):

As people already pointed out you're looking for `@OneToOne` and a guide on JPA. Here's a rudimentary approach on this:

Class table1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
public class table1{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    // omitting constructors, getters, setters, toString, etc.
}
```

Class table2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table2")
public class table2{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne // using default values for db schema
    private table1 t1; // notice how you have an actual reference to your object

    // omitting constructors, getters, setters, toString, etc.
}
```

A demo:

```
public void demo() {
    table1 t1 = new table1("my table1 object");
    t1 = t1Repo.save(t1);

    table2 t2 = new table2("my table2 object", t1);
    t2 = t2Repo.save(t2);

    for (table2 t : t2Repo.findAll()) {
        log.info("retrieved t2 object " + t);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
retrieved t2 object table2{Id=1, name='my table2 object', t1=table1{Id=1, name='my table1 object'}}
```

This is how the corresponding MySQL looks like:

```
MariaDB [so41334487]> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_so41334487 |
+----------------------+
| table1               |
| table2               |
+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [so41334487]> describe table1;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)

MariaDB [so41334487]> describe table2;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| t1_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [so41334487]> select * from table1;
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | my table1 object |
+----+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [so41334487]> select * from table2;
+----+------------------+-------+
| id | name             | t1_id |
+----+------------------+-------+
|  1 | my table2 object |     1 |
+----+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here's the corresponding `CREATE` statement extracted from `SHOW CREATE TABLE table2`:

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `t1_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FK30i46miycdu2aqony71wj8kva` (`t1_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK30i46miycdu2aqony71wj8kva` FOREIGN KEY (`t1_id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

There's lots of high quality content out there including books and video lectures on `@OneToOne` and corresponding pitfalls, however if you're looking for a quick heads-up you can start [in the WikiBook on JavaPersistence](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Common_Problems). Also keep in mind that chaining `FetchType.EAGER` may cause you to load your entire database into memory if you create circular references among (a chain of) objects.

Comment: Thank you for your replay , I try to write like you did but an error happen on the property @OneToOne , how the mysql  will get the id of a foreign key if the property will set as an object of table1 ?

Comment: A) Could you please provide the error message?  B) Since the property is an object annotated with `@Entity` your JPA implementation is aware of the object's database structure which includes what the primary key is. That way it can map the property via foreign key.